# Архитектура c RabbitMQ и SingalR .net

Tags: c#, архитектура, rabbitmq, signalr

Здравствуйте, мой вопрос касательно архитектуры, точнее его смысла. Я залез в эту тему, до конца не понимая в чем смысл **RabbitMQ** и **SignalR**.
Есть следующая архитектура:

- *клиент* (в качестве которого может быть asp.net mvc и win form
  приложение); Клиенты обмениваются сообщениями друг с другом с помощью
  **SignalR** обменивается сообщениями между клиентами.
- Также с другой стороны есть *сервис*, который помещает сообщения в
  **RabbitMQ**. Соответственно эти сообщения должны приходить клиентам через подписку на эти сообщения, а сообщения отправленные с клиентов,
  также попадать в очередь в **RabbitMQ**.

Вопрос в следующем: нужен ли в этой архитектуре **SignalR**? и если да, то, что делать с дублями, ведь когда сообщения отправляются с клиента, происходит публикация сообщения в **RabbitMQ** и вместе с этим отправка этого сообщения через **SignalR** другим клиентам, которые и так подписаны на эти сообщения из **RabbitMQ**.

Comment: Если у вас есть какая то система, и вы никак не можете понять какая от неё польза - то скорее всего вам эта система не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Технология SignalR предназначена для приложений, которым необходимо создать двунаправленную связь клиента и сервера. В классических веб-приложениях инициатором какого-либо обмена данными выступает клиент, который делает запрос, в то время как в двунаправленном приложении обмен может быть инициирован также со стороны сервера.
В силу этого, технология SignalR хорошо подходит для создания приложений обмена сообщениями - серверу необходимо мгновенно сигнализировать клиенту о том, что ему пришло новое сообщение и он сможет это делать.

Технология RabbitMQ, как и прочие брокеры, предназначена для обмена событиями, которые происходят в разных независимых частях вашего приложения. Обмен событиями происходит с помощью сообщений, но не нужно путать эти сообщения с сообщениями мессенджера. Брокеры сообщений обычно применяются на бекенде в микросервисной среде (если вы поместите взаимодействие с брокером в клиентское приложение, которое вы по сути не контролируете, то вам придётся задуматься о защите брокера от атак и прочих вытекающих проблемах).

На вашем примере можно пояснить разницу следующим образом. Если вашим клиентам нужен только мгновенный обмен сообщениями, то можно просто использовать SignalR. Если же к приложению начинает предъявляться требование хранения истории сообщений, то на бекенде вам необходимо организовать базу данных и сохранение туда сообщений.

Если операции обработки обмена сообщений и сохранения в базу делать в рамках одного приложения, то мощностей одной машины может быстро стать недостаточно. Для решения этой проблемы как раз и нужны брокеры событий. При решении этой задачи делают разнесение процессов обработки обмена сообщениями и сохранение/просмотр исторических по разным приложениям с обменом данными через RabbitMQ - когда сообщение получено, публикуется событие об этом, а сервис сохранения истории получает событие и добавляет его в контекст БД.

Таким образом, на сегодняшний день брокеры сообщений имеет смысл применять только для связи приложений на бекенде, добавлять RabbitMQ в ваше фронт-приложение не следует.